# Cloudify and network

Tags: openstack, cloudify

I am using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Icehouse.

I would like know if Cloudify allows to attach a running Application VM to an existing network.

Does it exist a specific Rest API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudify 2.7 allows you to specify a compute template which should connect to existing network. An example is available here:
https://gist.github.com/tamirko/8040538#file-computenetwork-groovy

There is no additional API to call - the network setup is declarative.

Please note the Cloudify 2.X has reached end of life and is no longer supported. You should try out Cloudify 3

Comment: OK. But can I change the compute template of a running Cloudify Application VM?

Comment: Maybe, could I change the compute template for a running Cloudify Application VM?

Comment: You can'y chance the template of a running VM. You can add new compute template in runtime (see the add-templates cli command) but these can only be used for new services and VMs